# Use value of entity field to delimite form:input max value

Tags: java, jsp

I have a field in my form to introduce quantity of a shipment related to a contract. Shipment don't need to be al quantity of the contract, it can be splitted in different shipments, but for sure, quantity of the shipment is not allowed to be greater than quantity of contract.

I can limit when submitting form, or validate via javascript but i like more to dont allow user to make mistakes :).

I want to know if I can assign the max propertie of the `<form:input>` dinamically when writting the jsp like i do with spring variables `<spring:message>` tags with `${cantidadPH}`.

That works perfect in the placeholder:

```
<spring:message code="logicomex.transporte.cantidad.placeholder" var="cantidadPH"/>
<form:input id="cantidad" path="cantidad" type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control" placeholder="${cantidadPH}" />
```

But when I try to use *"same technique"* for max value, something like this:

```
<form:hidden id="cantidadMax" path="contratMercan.cantidadMax" />
<form:input id="cantidad" path="cantidad" type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control" max="${cantidadMax}" placeholder="${cantidadPH}" />
```

It does not process `${cantidadMax}` as espected.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** The backing method is like this:

The class acting like a backing bean is TransporteFormHelper:

```
public class TransporteFormHelper extends Transporte implements Serializable {
```

`Transporte` entity has `ContratMercan` attribute, so overriden in `TransporteFormHelper` you can find:

```
@Override
public ContratMercan getContratMercan() {
    return super.getContratMercan();
}
```

Inside ContratMercan there is the max quantity field which must be used to set `max` attribute of the `<form:input>` field.

```
private double cantidadMax;
```

**NOTE:** *This is not my code, im rebuilding a premade app, so i have to carry this backing system I've never used before.* ;)

**EDIT2:** @grid, that seems not be working...

```
<c:set var="cantidadMax" value="${transporteFormHelper.contratMercan.cantidadMax}" />
<form:input id="cantidad" path="cantidad" type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control" max="${cantidadMax}" placeholder="${cantidadPH}" />
```

*please note, `path="cantidad"` is referencing `transporteFormHelper.cantidad`, i've tryed also with `${contratMercan.cantidadMax}` and `${transporteFormHelper.contratMercan.cantidadMax}`and both of them does not set the `max` attribute*

Comment: can you show the java bean code that is backing this jsp code

Comment: path="contratMercan.cantidadMax"  without ${}

Comment: in the `path` is working ok, but i want to set `max` attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are not actually using the exact same technique. Only partially. You don't set a *cantidadMax* variable as with var in the *cantidadPH* case. 
You should use a variable again i.e.

```
<c:set var="cantidadMax" value="${yourCommandObjectName.contratMercan.cantidadMax}" />
```

before referencing it. Currently you are using the hidden field id.

Comment: is there any getCandidadMax() accessor in ContratMercan ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use directly a JSTL expression for `max` attribute value. Say the bean backing the form is `myBean` (`<form:form commandName="myBean" ...>`), you could write :

```
<form:input id="cantidad" path="cantidad" type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control" max="${myBean.cantidadMax}" placeholder="${cantidadPH}" />
```

Or any other JSTL expression leading to `cantidadMas`.

EDIT

With your last edits showing your beans, you should write :

```
<form:input id="cantidad" path="cantidad" type="number" step="0.1" class="form-control" max="${transporteFormHelper.contratMercan.cantidadMax}" placeholder="${cantidadPH}" />
```

provided the bean implementing TransporteFormHelper be a request attribute with name `transporteFormHelper`

Comment: In my code: <form:form ..... method="post" commandName="transporte" ... > i try to use transporte.cantidadMax or cantidadMax but this is not working...

Comment: I've tryed that first of all, but unfortunatelly it does not work.